# resolving npm shrinkwrap peer invalid dependencies

Tags: npm, shrinkwrap

I've inherited a react/node/prismic application that uses shrinkwrap, and we need to update the prismic-reactjs package. That package requires higher versions of react and webpack, so I updated those in package.json too, and based on some npm dependency reading I've been roughly following these steps:

```
rm -fr node_modules
npm uninstall [package_name]
npm prune
npm cache clean
npm install [package_name]
npm shrinkwrap (to check missing dependencies)
npm install
npm shrinkwrap
```

That last shrinkwrap step shows the remaining "npm ERR! peer invalid:" statements, so I've been working my way top to the bottom of the list, and I'm now down to only three of them:

```
npm ERR! peer invalid: webpack@^3.1.0, required by extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2
npm ERR! peer invalid: react@^15.6.1, required by react-dom@15.6.1
npm ERR! peer invalid: react@^15, required by react-router-dom@4.1.2
```

Uh oh- it looks like those peer dependencies need the older versions I'd had for webpack (I updated 3.12.0 -> 4.0.0) and react (I updated 15.6.1 -> 16.0.0).

Of those 3 other packages, one is deprecated so I can't upgrade it if I tried. I could try updating the other 2, but I'm not sure if this is yak shaving- is there a better way forward? Is it possible to have both/conflicting packages in use?

Comment: I've had to deal with a similar situation yesterday. What I ended up doing was upgrading all dependencies to be compatible with the webpack and react versions I had, and manually upgrading all packages that were not compatible with those versions. Also it meant I had to do a few syntax changes in the app also, but I think the best way is just update.

Comment: Yes I think you're right- I've updated the two other packages, and now swapped out the suggested recommendation for the deprecated one, and at least shrinkwrap is happy again- it's a good feeling! Now I need to call the right methods in the new package so the code will run again...